# Tests en NestJS TypeError: this.tokenService.createToken is not a function

Tags: jest, nestjs, moongose

Cuando ejecuto un testeo en mi Backend hecho con NestJS me da un error que no consigo solucionar, al ejecutar el Backend normalmente si que funciona a la perfección, el problema solo ocurre al ejecutar el Back en modo test.

Este es el código de mi test:

```
   import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CreateTokenService } from '../../application/services/create.token.service';
import { CreateTokenController } from './create.token.controller';

describe('CreateTokenController', () => {
  let createTokenController: CreateTokenController;

  const mockTokenService = {
    create: jest.fn((dto) => {
      return {
        id: Date.now(),
        ...dto,
      };
    }),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CreateTokenController],
      providers: [CreateTokenService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(CreateTokenService)
      .useValue(mockTokenService)
      .compile();

    createTokenController = moduleRef.get<CreateTokenController>(
      CreateTokenController,
    );
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(createTokenController).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should create a token', async () => {
    const dto = { id: Date.now(), key: 'token', num_busquedas: 1 };
    expect(createTokenController.createToken(dto)).toEqual({
      id: expect.any(Number),
      key: dto.key,
      num_busquedas: dto.num_busquedas,
    });

    expect(mockTokenService.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dto);
  });
});
```

Este es el Error que me da el código al testearlo:

[image: TypeError is not a function]

Comment: Te está diciendo que tu mock no tiene la función que esperaba. ¿Será que estás *mockeando* una función `create` cuando debería ser `createToken`?

Comment: @PabloLozano Muchas gracias, vaya error mas tonto jajaja

Comment: Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para conocer el sitio y [ask] para entender el tipo de preguntas que solemos responder aquí. He votado positivo la pregunta porque está bien planteada y eso ayudó a encontrar rápidamente el problema. Pero puesto que el problema es un error tipográfico, también he votado para cerrarla.